# Time of Flight Estimation using cross correlation

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, waveform, cross-correlation

I am doing an experiment to find phase velocity of material by  through-transmission method.I have two received signals at  different distance as csv files.You can see the figures below;

[image: received_1]
[image: receivedd_2]

I want to use cross correlation method to find time of flight.I used the matlab code for the cross correlation which is given below:

```
 clc
  clear all

 % received signal 1
   data = read_tektronix_csv('TEK0058.CSV');
   plot(data.time, data.values)
   s1=data.values;

%received signal 2
   data = read_tektronix_csv('TEK0059.CSV');
   plot(data.time, data.values)
   s2=data.values;

   [acor,lag] = xcorr(s1,s2);
   Fs=1E9;

[~,I] = max(abs(acor));
lagDiff = lag(I)
timeDiff = lagDiff/Fs

figure
plot(lag,acor)
```

That matlab code gave me 3.17E-7 second as a time of flight.The true time of fligt has to be 4.881E-5.

As you can see figure below,cross correlation was obtained from two received signals.

[image]

Is there any problem on code algorithm?

Thank you.

Comment: Provide links to data?

Comment: @AhmedFasih here is the link for data  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71949541/stack.tar.gz